# WithMockUser only works with MockMvcBuilders but not TestRestTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, mockito, jwt, integration-testing

I've read a couple of tutorials, for integration tests. They recommend using TestRestTemplate to make the requests. However, when I do

```
restTemplate.postForObject()
```

It doesn't respect @WithMockUser I don't think, I get an exception like

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:60196/api/v1/users": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode

    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.postForObject(TestRestTemplate.java:422)
    at UseControllerIT.createUser_AsAdmin_Test(UseControllerIT.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1710)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.RestTemplateExchangeTags.getStatusMessage(RestTemplateExchangeTags.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.RestTemplateExchangeTags.status(RestTemplateExchangeTags.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.DefaultRestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider.getTags(DefaultRestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.getTimeBuilder(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
    ... 43 more
```

However, in my *unit tests*, when I make the HTTP request via

```
mockMvc.perform(request)
```

@WithMockUser does work and bypass the need to pass in JWT token.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mocked user that's managed by `@WithMockUser` is thread-based and `MockMvc` and `TestRestTemplate` have different threading models.

When you use `MockMvc` the HTTP layer and servlet container are mocked out and the call from your test is made directly into Spring MVC's dispatcher servlet all on the same thread. In this situation the mock user is available.

When you use `TestRestTemplate`, you're making a full-blown HTTP request. This request is sent on the thread that your test is running on, and handled by a different thread on the server. In this situation, the mock user is not available on the thread that handles the request as it is a different thread to the one that configured the mock user and made the request.

Comment: ok that makes a lot of sense now that I think about it. But then what is the standard practise to get past JWT (or even oauth) with integration test? Is it to (1) go back to MockMVC? (2) Fetch a real JWT token first but then the different test cases would be dependent on each other which is not ideal or (3) MockBean out some of the classes that verify the token but thats not easy either because code also checks for authority and principle as well.